# 6 Fragments hided/shown by ViewPager without being dismissed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmenttransaction

I have 6 Fragments within an activity that I created as 
I want to swipe from one to the other and need them to not being dismissed but onyl hide/show y the viewpager.

Is there a way to derive a viewpager class or a SectionsPagerAdapter to do that.

I already add

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
```

but it didn't work. When swiping from the 4th fragment to 3rd or to 5th, the app crashes.

Relevant parts of my code *simpified and renamed Fragment classes to get the code readable*:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // create the fragment once for all !
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance(1);
        fragment2 = Fragment2.newInstance(2);
        fragment3 = Fragment3.newInstance(3);
        fragment4 = Fragment4.newInstance(4);
        fragment5 = Fragment5.newInstance(5);
        fragment6 = Fragment6.newInstance(6);
     }
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
    });


    public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public Fragment1() {
    }

    public static Fragment1 newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Fragment1fragment = new Fragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.setRetainInstance( true);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        // "Main Frag"
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // The activity is about to become visible again, recalcule  
    }
}



   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0 : return fragment1;   //instead  of Fragment1.newInstance(1);
            case 1 : return fragment2;
            case 2 : return fragment3; 
            case 3 : return fragment4;
            case 4 : return fragment5;
            case 5 : return fragment6;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 6 total pages.
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            case 3:
                return "SECTION 4";
            case 4:
                return "SECTION 5";
            case 5:
                return "SECTION 6";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your section pager adapter by FragmentSatePagerAdaper
And set
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);

Comment: @Rahul.thanks but it didn't solve my problem. I discovered meanwhile that the crash is du to the use of an xml for the 4th fragment that uses;

Comment: <tablefixheaders.TableFixHeaders xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />